# Gradle Error : Class not found exception

Tags: sqlite, gradle, javafx

How can i add sqlite drivers in my project. I am compiling a javafx project with gradle but it always stuck on drivers.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b8'
    classpath 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.10.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'myproject.MyProject'
version = '8u40'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
ios {
    forceLinkClasses = ['myproject.**.*']
}
android {
    applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.myproject'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the SQLite driver as a dependency to your project using gradle.

The most popular sqlite jdbc driver is from `org.xerial` and is [available at maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc). You can select the version and select the tab `gradle`, copy it and paste it in your `build.gradle`. For example :

```
 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.9.1'
```

Comment: I have added maven repository and classpath 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.10.1' but problem is still same

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` file and your `stacktrace` in your question.

Comment: Edit your question and add everything there.